# Linux cURL XML file POST - how to check for error/success?

Tags: linux, curl

I am using cURL to post a XML file on Linux as follows:

```
curl -X POST --header "Content-Type: text/xml" -d @test.xml "https://www.example.com"
```

How can I check the status of the cURL command to see if the file was posted or not?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the response status of your operation using `-w %{http_code}`

```
curl -s -o out.txt -w %{http_code} http://www.example.com/
```

In this example `-s` means silent mode, and `-o out.txt` means to save the response(usually html) into a file.

For this above command, you'l have output `200` when its success.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I got you but you can basically check the return value of the curl command. The return value of the last command is stored in the variable `$?`.

Example:

```
curl -X POST --header "Content-Type: text/xml" -d @test.xml "https://www.example.com"
ret=$? # store return value for later usage in the error message
if [ $ret != 0 ] ; then
    echo "POST failed with exit code $ret"
fi
```

This list of possible error codes can be found at the bottom of the [man page](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html). They are very helpful for debugging.

Comment: Would it be better to test `$?` directly if it is done immediately after and only to check for the status of `curl`?

Comment: I'm storing it to populate the exit code to the error message. It is helpful for debugging.